# PHP Switch Statement Not Working

Tags: php

I have a switch statement and its not changing the variable for whatever reason. I define it by default as one, and $getpage will just echo out as 1, not 1,10. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Someone help please.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=memberarea.php">';
}
else {
    if (!isset($_GET['sex']) &&
       !isset($_GET['age']) &&
       !isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $_GET['age'] = "x";
        $_GET['sex'] = "x";
        $_GET['page'] = 1;
        $getage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['age']);
        $getsex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['sex']);
        $getpage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['page']);
    }
    else {
        if ($_GET['age'] != "12-15" ||
            $_GET['age'] != "16-18" ||
            $_GET['age'] != "19-25" ||
            $_GET['age'] != "26-35" ||
            $_GET['age'] != "36+") {
            $_GET['age'] = "x";
            $getage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['age']);
        }
        else {
            $getage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['age']);
        }

        if ($_GET['sex'] != "male" ||
           $_GET['sex'] != "female" ||
           $_GET['sex'] != "x") {
            $_GET['sex'] = "x";
            $getsex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['sex']);
        }
        else {
            $getsex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['sex']);
        }

        if (ctype_digit($_GET['page']) === FALSE || $_GET['page'] > 10) {
            $_GET['page'] = 1;
            $getpage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['page']);
        }
        else {
            $getpage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['page']);
        }

        if ($getsex === "all") {
            $getsex = "*";
        }
        if ($getage === "all") {
            $getage = "*";
        }

        switch($getpage) {
            case 1:
                $getpage = "1,10";
                break;
            case 2:
                $getpage = "11,20";
                break;
            case 3:
                $getpage = "21,30";
                break;
            case 4:
                $getpage = "31,40";
                break;
            case 5:
                $getpage = "41,50";
                break;
            case 6:
                $getpage = "51,60";
                break;
            case 7:
                $getpage = "61,70";
                break;
            case 8:
                $getpage = "71,80";
                break;
            case 9:
                $getpage = "81,90";
                break;
            case 10:
                $getpage = "91,100";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use different variable in case. It should work

Comment: Works fine for me... [Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ejq-xd2)

Comment: Default is not mandatory

Comment: Clarify: you set `$getpage` to "one" or 1?

Comment: Adding `$getpage = 1;` at the top and `echo $getpage;` at the end echos `1,10` for me.

Comment: paste whole code, this is working here

Comment: Show where $getpage is set initially.

Comment: @RUJordan in PHP, a switch statement performs a loose comparison

Comment: I posted the whole code, and after a few blocks of HTML I try to echo out $getpage and it just echos out 1

Comment: I just added the $getpage = 1 right above the switch statement in case something was going wrong, still wont work.

Comment: @George: Post the output of `var_dump($getpage);` first.

Comment: @George - there's nothing in your code above that echos out `$getpage`

Comment: @AmalMurali string(1) "1" and I'm echoing it in a differnet place in my code, still on the same page though

Comment: @RainFromHeaven are you saying that a switch statement will say that "one" == 1?

Comment: That's my bad, for some reason I thought you wrote `'1' or 1`. But no, not even PHP is talented enough to say that `'one' == 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a function for this (not a switch) since your output can be easily calculated from your input. You don't want to list every possible input and match it to a hard-coded output. This breaks as soon as you hit page 11. Instead, perform the calculations to arrive at each number via some simple math:

```
function get_range($page) {
    $cap = $page * 10;
    return $cap - 9 . "," . $cap;
}

echo get_range(7);
// prints "61,70"
```

Comment: That explains, but can you tell us what is wrong with the switch>

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with the switch, the conditional statement wasn't firing all the way though, but this is much smarter by far. +1'd and thank you very much. As soon as I can I'll choose this as the answer.